# Reverse function to obtain original input values

Tags: python, transformation, trigonometry

I have the following `get_angles` function that creates angles from `input_features`. The features returned by the function are being used to train a variational quantum circuit.

```py
def get_angles(x):
    beta0 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[1] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta1 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta2 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(x[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(x))
    
    return np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2])
```

As such:

```py
input_features = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`

# Transform the features
features = np.array(get_angles(input_features))
```

Now, I would like to reverse this operation by taking the final `features` values and transforming them back into the `input_features` values used in the `get_angles` function. Is there a way to reverse the `get_angles` function defined above?

Thanks in advance.

Expecting to receive the `input_features` from running the final `features` through a `get_reverse_angles` function, I tried multiple variations of a `get_reverse_angles` function such as the one below to no avail.

```py
def get_reverse_angles(angles):
    # Extract the angles
    beta2, neg_beta1, pos_beta1, neg_beta0, pos_beta0 = angles
    
    # Solve for x using trigonometric equations
    x0 = np.sqrt(2)
    x1 = np.sin(beta2 / 2) * np.sqrt(2)
    x2 = np.sin(pos_beta1 / 2) * np.sqrt(2)
    x3 = np.sin(pos_beta0 / 2) * np.sqrt(2)
    x4 = np.sin(neg_beta0 / 2) * np.sqrt(2)
    
    # Compute x0 using the first equation
    x0 = np.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + x2 ** 2 + x3 ** 2 + x4 ** 2)
    
    # Return the values of the reversed operation
    return np.array([x0, x1 * x0, x2 * x0, x3 * x0, x4 * x0])
```

The `get_reverse_angles` function returned [ 1.79350156  2.41835701  0.97063605  1.33346136 -1.33346136] as opposed to the expected [10 20 30 40 50] `input_features`.

Comment: This function is not uniquely defined for each input, as it is periodic. eg `input_features = array([0.34662404, 0.69324808, 1.41508651, 1.41508651, 1.41508651])` will give the same features as the `input_features[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This answer is rewritten based on additional comments by @camaya :***

1. [The overloaded get_angles_or_features function seems promising and almost does the trick, it only needs to work for larger input features, i.e., `input_features = [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979]`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137497/reverse-function-to-obtain-original-input-values#comment137762511_78137545)
2. [It may be worth trying given there is only one sample in input_features with 5 numbers of 5 elements each. The input data always contains 5 elements and is sorted in arbitrary order.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137497/reverse-function-to-obtain-original-input-values#comment137763394_78137545)

**So what do we have?!**

1. Incoming data `input_features = [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979]` - a list of unsorted integers.
2. Three variables are declared in the `get_angles` function:

   | Table "Stages of input data recovery" |
   | --- |

   | *Step* | *Variable* | *Elements involved in calculations* |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | beta0 | **input[1]** & **input[0]** it can be restored using **features[4]** |
   | 2 | beta1 | **input[2]** cannot be restored using **features[2]** too many variations |
   | 3 | beta2 | **input[:]** if you save **input[2]**, you can restore **(input[3], input[4])** or **(input[4], input[3])** using **features[0]** |

   *(`input[:] == input_features ;  def get_angles(x): return features[:]`)*

## Step 1

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union, List


def get_angles_or_features(
        input: Union[List[int], np.ndarray[float]]
        ) -> Union[np.ndarray, List, None]:
    """"""

    input_type = type(input).__name__
    # Check type input
    if not (input_type == 'ndarray' or input_type == 'list'):
        print("Input Error")
        return None
    # Processing get angles
    elif input_type == 'list':
        beta0 = (
            2 * np.arcsin((np.sqrt(input[1] ** 2))
                          / np.sqrt(input[0] ** 2 + input[1] ** 2 + 1e-12)
                          )
        )
        beta1 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2)
                          / np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2 + input[2] ** 2 + 1e-12)
                          )
        )
        beta2 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(input[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(input))
        )

        return np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2])

    # Restoring data input_features
    elif input_type == 'ndarray':
        beta0 = input[4]

        x0, x1, x2, x3, x4 = None, None, None, None, None

        start1 = datetime.now()
        for x0 in range(1, 100000):
            for x1 in range(1, 100000):
                if (check := beta0 == (
                    np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x1 ** 2)
                              / np.sqrt(x0 ** 2 + x1 ** 2 + 1e-12)))):
                    break
            if check:
                print("We spent on the selection "
                      f"of the first two elements: {datetime.now() - start1}")
                break

        return [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]


# input_features = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
input_features = [35, 50, 65, 80, 90]
# input_features = [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979]
# input_features = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# input_features = [99960, 99970, 99980, 99990, 99999]
# input_features = [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]


# Transform the features
features = np.array(get_angles_or_features(input_features))

print(f"input_features    >>> {input_features}")
print(f"features          >>> {features}")

# Restoring the original data input_features
restored_features = get_angles_or_features(features)

print(f"restored_features >>> {restored_features}")
```

*Output to the console:*

```
input_features    >>> [35, 50, 65, 80, 90]
features          >>> [ 2.3025178  -0.78539816  0.78539816 -0.96007036  0.96007036]
We spent on the selection of the first two elements: 0:00:25.827939
restored_features >>> [35, 50, None, None, None]
```

We are guaranteed to get the first two elements, but for this we used two nested for loops, the time complexity of this code is **O(n^2)** in the worst case.

## Step 2

**It is not possible to define the third element in the second step, you can only reduce the number of iterations for the third step.**

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union, List


def get_angles_or_features(
        input: Union[List[int], np.ndarray[float]]
        ) -> Union[np.ndarray, List, None]:
    """"""

    input_type = type(input).__name__
    # Check type input
    if not (input_type == 'ndarray' or input_type == 'list'):
        print("Input Error")
        return None
    # Processing get angles
    elif input_type == 'list':
        beta0 = (
            2 * np.arcsin((np.sqrt(input[1] ** 2))
                          / np.sqrt(input[0] ** 2 + input[1] ** 2 + 1e-12)
                          )
        )
        beta1 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2)
                          / np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2 + input[2] ** 2 + 1e-12)
                          )
        )
        beta2 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(input[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(input))
        )

        return np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2])

    # Restoring data input_features
    elif input_type == 'ndarray':
        beta0, beta1 = input[4], input[2]

        x0, x1, x2, x3, x4 = None, None, None, None, None

        # Step 1
        start1 = datetime.now()
        for x0 in range(1, 100000):
            for x1 in range(1, 100000):
                if (check := beta0 == (
                    np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x1 ** 2)
                              / np.sqrt(x0 ** 2 + x1 ** 2 + 1e-12)))):
                    break
            if check:
                print("We spent on the selection "
                      f"of the first two elements: {datetime.now() - start1}"
                      )
                break
        # Step 2
        start2 = datetime.now()
        _x2 = tuple(x for x in range(1, 100000)
                    if beta1 == np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x ** 2)
                                          / np.sqrt(x ** 2 + x ** 2 + 1e-12)
                                          )
                    )
        end2 = datetime.now()
        print("Reduced future iterations from 100000 "
              f"to {(_len := len(_x2))} and wasted time: {end2 - start2}"
              )
    return [x0, x1, (type(_x2), f"len: {_len}"), x3, x4]


# input_features = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
input_features = [35, 50, 65, 80, 90]
# input_features = [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979]
# input_features = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# input_features = [99960, 99970, 99980, 99990, 99999]
# input_features = [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]


# Transform the features
features = np.array(get_angles_or_features(input_features))

print(f"input_features    >>> {input_features}")
print(f"features          >>> {features}")

# Restoring the original data input_features
restored_features = get_angles_or_features(features)

print(f"restored_features >>> {restored_features}")
```

*Output to the console:*

```
input_features    >>> [35, 50, 65, 80, 90]
features          >>> [ 2.3025178  -0.78539816  0.78539816 -0.96007036  0.96007036]
We spent on the selection of the first two elements: 0:00:26.472476
Reduced future iterations from 100000 to 43309 and wasted time: 0:00:00.814264
restored_features >>> [35, 50, (<class 'tuple'>, 'len: 43309'), None, None]
```

***However, 43309 iterations of the first for loop is too expensive...***

This is due to the fact that only one element ***input_features*** is used to calculate ***beta1*** — this increases the inverse variability.

`beta1 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2 + 1e-12))`

*If it is acceptable to add one element to* ***features*** *for backward compatibility,*
*then the variability can be leveled.*

## Step 3

```py
from typing import Union, Tuple, List
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np


def get_angles_or_features(
        input: Union[List[int], np.ndarray[float]]
        ) -> Union[Tuple, None]:
    """"""

    input_type = type(input).__name__
    # Check type input
    if not (input_type == 'tuple' or input_type == 'list'):
        print("Input Error")
        return None

    # Processing get angles
    if input_type == 'list':
        beta0 = (
            2 * np.arcsin((np.sqrt(input[1] ** 2))
                          / np.sqrt(input[0] ** 2 + input[1] ** 2 + 1e-12)))
        beta1 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2)
                          / np.sqrt(input[2] ** 2 + input[2] ** 2 + 1e-12)))
        beta2 = (
            2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(input[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(input)))

        return (np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2,
                          -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2]), input[2])
    # Conversion angles
    elif input_type == 'tuple':
        beta0, beta2 = input[0][4], input[0][0] / 2
        x2 = int(input[-1])
        start, end = (x2 - 3500 if x2 - 3500 >= 0 else 0,
                      x2 + 3501 if x2 + 3501 <= 43000 else 43000)
        # Defining x0 & x1
        _x0_x1 = tuple(
            (x0, x1)
            for x0 in range(start, end)
            for x1 in range(start, end)
            if (0.46 < x2 / (x0 + x1) < 0.51
                and (beta0 == np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x1 ** 2)
                     / np.sqrt(x0 ** 2 + x1 ** 2 + 1e-12)))
                )
            )[0]
        x0, x1 = _x0_x1
        # Defining x3 & x4
        regeneraite_features = (
            [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]
            for x3 in range(start, end)
            for x4 in range(start, end)
            if (0.5 < x2 / (x3 + x4) < 0.54
                and (beta2 == np.arcsin(
                              np.linalg.norm([x2, x3, x4])
                              / np.linalg.norm([x0, x1, x2, x3, x4])))
                )
            )

        return tuple(regeneraite_features)


all_input_features = [
    [20979, 20583, 19433, 18988, 18687],
    [22689, 21849, 20979, 20583, 19433],
    [22962, 22689, 21849, 20979, 20583],
    [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979],
    [21849, 20979, 20583, 19433, 18988]
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for input_features in all_input_features:
        # Transform the features
        features = get_angles_or_features(input_features)

        print(f"\ninput_features     >>> {input_features}")
        print(f"features           >>> {features}")
        start_time = datetime.now()
        restored_features = get_angles_or_features(features)
        # print(f"restored_features  >>> {features}")
        print(f"restored_features  >>> {restored_features}")
        print(f"Duration of the recovery process: {datetime.now() - start_time}")
```

*Output to the console:*

```
input_features     >>> [20979, 20583, 19433, 18988, 18687]
features           >>> (array([ 1.6856525 , -0.78539816,  0.78539816, -0.77587052,  0.77587052]), 19433)        
restored_features  >>> ([20979, 20583, 19433, 18687, 18988], [20979, 20583, 19433, 18988, 18687])
Duration of the recovery process: 0:08:55.662949

input_features     >>> [22689, 21849, 20979, 20583, 19433]
features           >>> (array([ 1.68262106, -0.78539816,  0.78539816, -0.7665401 ,  0.7665401 ]), 20979)        
restored_features  >>> ([22689, 21849, 20979, 19433, 20583], [22689, 21849, 20979, 20583, 19433])
Duration of the recovery process: 0:09:29.221780

input_features     >>> [22962, 22689, 21849, 20979, 20583]
features           >>> (array([ 1.69663709, -0.78539816,  0.78539816, -0.77941808,  0.77941808]), 21849)        
restored_features  >>> ([22962, 22689, 21849, 19089, 22347], [22962, 22689, 21849, 20583, 20979], [22962, 22689, 21849, 20979, 20583], [22962, 22689, 21849, 22347, 19089])
Duration of the recovery process: 0:09:36.666942

input_features     >>> [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979]
features           >>> (array([ 1.73553479, -0.78539816,  0.78539816, -0.79794298,  0.79794298]), 22689)        
restored_features  >>> ([22393, 22962, 22689, 20979, 21849], [22393, 22962, 22689, 21849, 20979])
Duration of the recovery process: 0:10:10.256594

input_features     >>> [21849, 20979, 20583, 19433, 18988]
features           >>> (array([ 1.68858074, -0.78539816,  0.78539816, -0.76508714,  0.76508714]), 20583)        
restored_features  >>> ([21849, 20979, 20583, 18988, 19433], [21849, 20979, 20583, 19433, 18988])
Duration of the recovery process: 0:09:07.385657
```

***Good.*** When you save the `input[2]` you have the opportunity to get an acceptable result,
but it is still not absolutely pure.

**In addition, the duration of the recovery process is still very long.**

## Resume

We had to take these three steps to show that this approach is not effective enough.

When you process data that you will need in the future, keep the opportunity to access it.

***At least this way...***

```py
from typing import List, Union, Tuple, Dict
import numpy as np

def get_angles(x: List[int]
               ) -> Union[Tuple[np.ndarray, tuple], Dict[tuple, list]]:
    """"""

    beta0 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[1] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta1 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta2 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(x[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(x))
    
    return (np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2]),
            (x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4])
            )

    # or this way...
    return {(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]):
            [beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2]
            }
```

***You can go even further...***

```py
from typing import List
import numpy as np


@freeze_arguments
def get_angles(x: List[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    """"""

    beta0 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[1] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta1 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta2 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(x[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(x))
    
    return np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2])
```

### But that's a completely different story!

Comment: thanks for such a through evaluation at the problem. Given the situation, can we define a new get_angles function that generates angles in a similar format? I.e., redefine the original get_angles function so that a new function will be easier to reverse. The angles return amount and operations can vary according to what is practical so long as the input is a `list` or `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Hi! I'm just going to add a few code options now, and I'll describe them later when I have time. See the code in **Step 3**

Comment: Hey, thanks I look forward to seeing those options. I'm not able to get Step 3 to work, I think it's best if `get_angles` is redefined to make for easier inversion.

Comment: @camaya Give me 10 real-world examples of `input_features', maybe I'll shorten the processing time.

Comment: please see:

0   [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ]
1    [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ]
2   [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ]
3    [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ] 
4    [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ]
5    [ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ]
6    [ 22962 22689 21849 20979 20583 ]
7    [ 22689 21849 20979 20583 19433 ]
8    [ 21849 20979 20583 19433 18988 ]
9    [ 20979 20583 19433 18988 18687 ]

The reverse function will only be applied to the last set of angles, so in terms of processing time, get_angles() would require the bulk of it.

Comment: Of these 10, only 5 are unique.
And the order of the numbers is always in the range from 10000 to 30000? If there are, please give examples with different ranges.

Comment: I want to understand if there are dependencies between the elements of a separate set. In the examples that you gave, within a group of elements, the elements are in the range up to 2500 -- `[ 22393 22962 22689 21849 20979 ] 22962 - 20979 = 1983` or `[ 20979 20583 19433 18988 18687 ] 20979 - 18687 = 2292` . **I already asked earlier, but did not get an answer: can such a set [ 17 4387 99999 23744 300] exist?**

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The range for all the features is 0 - 43000, so each element can possibly have a value within that range but most samples tend to have elements that, according to your last question, vary only up to 3500.

Comment: [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137497/reverse-function-to-obtain-original-input-values/78137545?noredirect=1#comment137800112_78137545) very useful information, I'll take that into account.

Comment: thank you so much for this solution! This solves the problem by effectively restoring the data back to its original state after processing. Good work mate.